# Prove that for least curved surface area of a cone of given volume the altitude is $\sqrt 2$ times base radius

Tags: calculus

How to show that for a cone with given volume and least curved surface area the altitude is equal to $\sqrt2$ times the radius of the base, using concept of maxima and minima?

Answer (score 2):

Volume of a right circular cone, $$\mathbf{V = \frac{1}{3}\pi r^2h}$$ where **r** is the radius and **h** the altitude of the cone. Its curved surface area, $$\mathbf{CSA = \pi r\sqrt{r^2 + h^2}}$$ Now to make calculations easier we take our functions as $$\mathbf{(CSA)^2 = \pi^2 r^4 + \pi^2 r^2h^2}$$ and substitute $$\mathbf{r = \sqrt{\frac{3V}{\pi h}}}$$ (since volume is constant), giving us $$\mathbf{(CSA)^2 = \frac{9v^2}{h^2} + \pi 3Vh}$$ For minima : $$\mathbf{\frac{d}{dh}(CSA)^2 = 0}$$ and $$\mathbf{\frac{d^2}{dh^2}(CSA)^2 > 0}$$ To find relation between **r** and **h**, $$\mathbf{\frac{d}{dh}(CSA)^2 = -\frac{18V^2}{h^3} + \pi 3V = 0}$$ 
$$\mathbf{\Rightarrow h = \left(\frac{6V}{\pi}\right)^{1/3}}$$
$$\mathbf{\Rightarrow r = \left(\frac{3V}{\sqrt2 \pi}\right)^{1/3}}$$
$$\mathbf{\Rightarrow h = \sqrt{2} \times r}$$ To confirm it is indeed minima, $$\mathbf{\frac{d^2}{dh^2}(CSA)^2 = \frac{54V^2}{h^4} > 0}$$

Answer (score 0):

Given with a hope to induce interest for learning the more powerful Lagrange multiplier when there are two variables.

$$ A = r \sqrt {r^2+h^2},\, V = r^2h\,$$

the method requires taking a Lagrangian like $(A- \lambda V),$

$$ \dfrac{A_r}{A_h}= \dfrac{V_r}{V_h} $$

where these are partial derivatives of $ A,V $  w.r.t. subscripts $(r,h)$ given

$$\dfrac{ \sqrt {r^2+h^2} +r^2/\sqrt {r^2+h^2}}{rh/\sqrt {r^2+h^2}}= \dfrac{2 r h}{r^2} $$

which when simplified results in:

$$ \dfrac{h}{r} =\sqrt {2}. $$

Answer (score 0):

Put $h=\lambda r$ for some $\lambda>0$ yet to be determined. Then
$$V={1\over3}\pi r^3\lambda,\qquad A=\pi r\sqrt{r^2+h^2}=\pi r^2\sqrt{1+\lambda^2}\ .$$
We now eliminate $r$ by considering
$$A^3=\pi^3 r^6(1+\lambda^2)^{3/2}=9\pi V^2\cdot{(1+\lambda^2)^{3/2}\over\lambda^2}\ .$$
With $\lambda\to0+$ and $\lambda\to\infty$ the  factor $\psi(\lambda)$ on the RHS goes to $\infty$. Since $\psi'(\lambda)$ has a unique zero at $\lambda=\sqrt{2}$ it follows that for given $V$ the area $A$ is minimal when $\lambda=\sqrt{2}$.